# What is ">ul" means in SASS?

Tags: sass, stylus

Here is the SASS code part:

```
#main-nav{
     >ul{
              blahblah
        }
}
```

So I want to know the exact mean of the string ">ul" means? I cannot find it in the SASS manual.

Furthermore, can it be translated to stylus?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators

Comment: The grammatical way to ask this question is 'What does ">ul" mean in SASS?'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This the CSS syntax to select the child of an element. See [this reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) for more on how it works:

> This selector matches all elements that are the immediate children of
>   a specified element. The combinator in a child selector is a
>   greater-than sign (>). It may be surrounded by whitespace characters,
>   but if it is, Internet Explorer 5 on Windows will incorrectly treat it
>   as a descendant selector. So the best practice is to eschew whitespace
>   around this combinator.

Comment: I think it's okay to ignore internet explorer 5 compatibility at this point.. Except maybe for highly specialized situations

Answer (score 12):

```
#main-nav {
    > ul {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

The same in CSS:

```
#main-nav > ul { color: red }
```

About `>` selector you can read here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/ (#8)